# What happens to the abusive monk?

Tags: vinaya, dhammapada

I know a person who is fairly expert on Dhamma and in early times practised well; meditating up to 10 hours per day. But today this person spends at least five hours per day doing physical rehabilitation due to an unfortunate injury. Yet this person is constantly harassed by a troll monk who insists this rehabilitating person become a monk. While this person spends 5 hours per day doing rehabilitation, this monk appears to spend 5 hours per day trolling the internet rather than practising meditation. For example, sometimes when this person wants to sit, their body must walk. Other times, when this person wants to walk, their body must sit. Sometimes they want to quietly breathe, but the body may cough (which would disturb other monks).

What happens to the abusive monk whose actions can cause distress & trauma (to a similar fool)? Are there any suttas about what happens to evil characters and uncontrolled men wearing the saffron robe?

Answer (score 1):

Kamma isn't different working for monk or householder, good householder. Yet sure, people love victim-blaming. To judge right could be just made for both individual seperate. Neither can be assumed that the one experience discomfort really knowns the reason, nor could it be garanted that assumed 'trolling' is really such. Sick people tend to blame even helping hands, like dogs easy bite even their keeper.

Of what's kusala, what's not, good householder knows, at least literary. Why trying to pain a pointless outwardly judgement? Buddhism doesn't work like that.

Why not seeking direct approach and solve the issue, but instead seek after a small world-war approaching others when kamma starts ripping?

It may of course happen that somebody used to troll gets trolled, or at least feels as if. Remembering a little on own old deeds might help, not only to be able to bear vipaka but also to finally stop doing evil minded things.

If the answer doesn't releases, but even causes anger in addition: well, no way to help one already on the road downwardly.

Good householder knows well the reason of his vipaka, and if he would have practiced correct at any time of his life, instead of developing samadhi based on wrong view, he would have arrived at right view already, would no more have doubts nor would he try to charge others for his own heritage, his past and present deeds. Who would have compassion with someone who used to harm, still harms, Noble Ones, aside of a Noble One? Others might take side in hope for own gains, of course.

Just stop it, and turn to good friends. Confessing, pardon and simply leading a good and virtuous life, having found refuge maybe right here for the first time.

While others might provide happily weapons, my person likes to remind that there isn't much time left and real duty, that of leaving house and stand, still not done. Sure, some believe that there is no life after, but why they then nevertheless seek for heavens and fear hell even here... Stop it! For goid householders own sake, nobody else bears the fruits, here or in next existence. Remember, much sickness is caused by tendency of harming others and trolling around.

Understand?

[image]

Comment: this answer appears to confuse Buddhism for Christianity; trying to save others. it appears contrary to the life of a Buddhist renunciate

Comment: Fools already on the road to hell usually can only increase the speed. Nobody can help good Dhammadhatu... what ever disguise, any more. It all started by harming the Noble ones. Here you "are". Nothing but own kamma can be blamed.

Comment: sorry but this is not an answer to the question. the question is about uncontrolled monks trolling in internet and not following the Buddha's Path

Comment: which Noble Ones was harmed? what happened to those Noble Ones? how were they harmed?

Comment: Only a fool or a silly dog, regard a helping hand as enemy. Only one who stopped trolling (disturbe with evil mind) knows the different. For a fool help appears as trolling.

Comment: Good householder, as often told, harmed good monks and nuns a lot and now cries for victim-blame, now as he can no more escape the kamma. Calls for "EU, US...Nato" See, I am poor! Simply stop and leave home/stand. Good to stop the Asura within own heart first.

Comment: This comment appears to be victim-blaming others for harming Noble Ones. Its a very confusing comment.

Comment: Not at all. The "abusive monk" lives comfortable under the Khema, holds neither any rights, nor hinders one in doing either good or bad. It's householders good choice that leads to increase or leaving suffering behind.

Comment: sorry but the "abusive monk" trolls the worldly internet and is not viveka. the "abusive monk" appears engaged in false speech declaring false attainments which is a parajika offense. Defeat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134545/discussion-between-stop-obama-biden-stop-war-and-user23514).

Comment: Good householder is always welcome to access Noble Domain forum.sangham.net if wishing for going to refuge under all three Gems. Why using the "enemies" means? That's inhonest, the lefties ways, not that of dhammika.

Comment: sorry but MN 95 says the householder examines the monk for states of greed, hatred and delusion. sorry but this householder has zero faith in Johann. forum.sangham.net = Mara forum

Comment: work finished for the day. layperson must work to make money; just like monk must be virtuous to earn a livelihood (unless the monk lives in dependence on a virtuous monk). time to finish with internet now.

Comment: Dont must: like, desire. What ever one desires, there he is bond. Some have already done all duties, but one without right view thinks all are as equal foolish and bond like him. Not willing to leave house, one stays slave of his desires, stays slave and even heads down.

Answer (score 0):

No one escapes their kamma (good or bad). Doesn't matter if its a layperson or monastic.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. The system flagged this as a low quality answer. This answer is too short and doesn't contain enough details. Also, if possible, it is preferred to cite sources to support the answer. Did you intend it to be a [comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question? If not, please see [this guide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

The suttas appear to provide one answer as follows:

> 307. There are many evil characters and uncontrolled men wearing the saffron robe. These wicked men will be born in states of woe because
>      of their evil deeds.
> 308. It would be better to swallow a red-hot iron ball, blazing like fire, than as an immoral and uncontrolled monk to eat the alms of the
>      people.
>
> Dhammapada